# How can I create Bulk CRUD Operations request in Elasticsearch version 8 using JAVA APIs?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

We wanted to create **IndexRequest**, **DeleteRequest**, **UpdateRequest** and **BulkRequest** in **Elasticsearch version 8** using **JAVA APIs**. But I don't see any java documentation in elasticsearch v8 [official website](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html). Previously in elasticsearch version 7, we used below code in order to perform operations.

```
IndexRequest indexRequest = Requests.indexRequest(index).id(key).source(source);


BulkRequest bulkRequest = Requests.bulkRequest();
bulkRequest.add(indexRequest);
```

Also following [Elasticsearch Java API Client [8.1]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/introduction.html) , but no luck.

Problem arises when we try to do `Requests.`indexRequest(), this **Request** class is not available in version 8.

So, Is it possible to create similar request in ES version 8 also?

**Update 1:-**

My point here is that I need to keep a list of request operation which maybe arbitrary ( maybe 1st five are inserts, next 2 are update and next 2 are delete requests and at the end 1 insert operation ). And that list needed to be flushed via Bulk maintaining the type of request received. I am using `BulkRequest.Builder bulkRequestBuilder = new BulkRequest.Builder();`

But my issue is with bulk update. I am unable to find any update API for bulkrequest for elasticsearch version 8.

For Insert:-

```
bulkRequestBuilder.operations(op -> op.index(idx -> idx.index(index).id(key).document(source)));
```

For Delete:-

```
bulkRequestBuilder.operations(op -> op.delete(d -> d.index(index).id(key)));
```

And flushing the bulk operation:-

```
BulkResponse bulkResponse = client.bulk(bulkRequestBuilder.build());
```

I am looking for something similar to above mentioned insert and delete operation.

Like, `bulkRequestBuilder.operations(op->op.update(u->u.index(index).id(key)....))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Fluent DSL** like below as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/indexing-bulk.html#_indexing_application_objects):

```java
List<Product> products = fetchProducts();

BulkRequest.Builder br = new BulkRequest.Builder();

for (Product product : products) {
    br.operations(op -> op           
        .index(idx -> idx            
            .index("products")       
            .id(product.getSku())
            .document(product)
        )
    );
}

BulkResponse result = esClient.bulk(br.build());
```

You can use **Classic Builder** like below (Not Recommndate):

```java
IndexRequest.Builder<Product> indexReqBuilder = new IndexRequest.Builder<>();
indexReqBuilder.index("product");
indexReqBuilder.id("id");
indexReqBuilder.document(product);
        
List<BulkOperation> list = new ArrayList<BulkOperation>();
list.add(indexReqBuilder);
        
BulkRequest.Builder br = new BulkRequest.Builder();
br.index("");
br.operations(list);
        
client.bulk(br.build());
```

**Update Request:**

As mentioned [here](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch-java/8.1.3/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/core/UpdateRequest.Builder.html) in document, UpdateRequest class support `TDocument` and `TPartialDocument` as parameter. when you want to index document as parial document (means only update) then you can use `TPartialDocument` and when you want to index document as upsert then you can use `TDocument`. you can pass `Void` class for other parameter.

You can check [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/7-16-java-client-updaterequest-example/295846/3) discussion as well which give you some understanding.

```java
client.update(b -> b
                .index("")
                .id("")
                .doc(product),
                Product.class
            );
```

```java
client.update(new UpdateRequest.Builder<Void, Product>()
                .index("product")
                .id("")
                .doc(product)
                .build(),
                Void.class
            );
```

**Bulk Update request:**

```java
BulkRequest.Builder br = new BulkRequest.Builder();
for (Product product : products) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(product);
    br.operations(op -> op
                    .update(idx -> idx.index("products").id("").withJson(new StringReader(json))));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your solution as well as @Amit's solution helped me a lot. Can you help me in how to create `UpdateRequest` in elasticsearch version 8. Similar to below version 7 code.  

`UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest().index(index).id(key).doc(source).docAsUpsert(isUpsert);`

Comment: I have updated my answer. please check. there are no example available for `UpdateRequest` so difficult to implement.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar Patel, Although your answer regarding UpdateRequest is suitable for older elasticsearch version. But can you help me in finding solution for updaterequest in bulk for elasticsearch version 8.

Comment: @PiyushKumar answer which i have posted it is for version 8 only. they dont have `upsert` method in new version.  if you want to pass partial document then you need to pass `<Void, Product>`  and if document as `upsert` then you need to pass `<Product,Void>`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your solution helped me a lot. But my point here is that I need to keep a list of request operation which maybe arbitrary ( maybe 1st five are inserts, next 2 are update and next 2 are delete requests and at the end 1 insert operation ). And that list needed to be flushed via Bulk maintaining the type of request received. I am using `BulkRequest.Builder bulkRequestBuilder`.

continue.........

Comment: cont...

For insert :- `bulkRequestBuilder.operations(op -> op.index(idx -> idx.index(index).id(key).document(source)));`

For delete:- `bulkRequestBuilder.operations(op -> op.delete(d -> d.index(index).id(key)));`

and at the end I am doing it, ` BulkResponse bulkResponse = client.bulk(bulkRequestBuilder.build());`

But my issue is with bulk update. I am unable to find any update API for bulkrequest. Can you help me in this regard.

Comment: am looking for something similar mentioned below, but I am not able to add update document map in bulk update operation, 

`bulkRequestBuilder.operations(op->op.update(u->u.index(index).id(key)))`

Comment: @PiyushKumar as far as i know it will be same as insert and delete. something like `bulkRequestBuilder.operations(op -> op.update(d -> d.index(index).id(key),Void.class))`

Comment: But where should I add my updated document, void.class I understand but what about newly added field, which needed to be updated ?

Comment: @PiyushKumar You need to pass `.doc(product)` for your document same as you are passing for index request like `bulkRequestBuilder.operations(op -> op.update(d -> d.index(index).id(key).doc(product),Void.class))`

Comment: Unfortunately , `.doc(product)` method is not available.

Comment: @PiyushKumar Sorry my bad. you  need to convert your object to the json and then pass . i have updated my answer please check

Answer (score 1):

You can use the refer the following code which I used to bulk index.

```
String PRODUCT_INDEX="product"
final BulkResponse bulkResponse = esUtil.getESClient().bulk(builder -> {
                for (Product product : products) {
                    builder.index(PRODUCT_INDEX)
                            .operations(ob -> {
                                ob.index(ib -> ib.document(product).pipeline("score").id(product.getId())));
                                return ob;
                            });
                }
                return builder;
            });
```